# FunctionExpand does not yield known simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Consider:

```
Cosh[a ArcSinh[z]] // FunctionExpand
```

> `Cosh[a ArcSinh[z]]`

Which seems to suggest that there is no simplification that can be done here. However, there is an identity on the [wolfram functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cosh/16/01/02/07/0004/) site that states

```
Cosh[a ArcSinh[z]] == ((1/2) (1 + (z + Sqrt[1 + z^2])^(2 a)))/(z + Sqrt[1 + z^2])^a
```

which is clearly a simplification. Why did `FunctionExpand` not recognize this and what should I do in future to make Mathematica see this sort of simplification directly without looking it up on a webpage?

Comment: Hi; it is a funny thing about simplifications...If I substitute random reals for a and z I get that the RHS is almost 3 times slower than the LHS to compute.

Comment: @bobbym That makes sense. But analytically trigonometric functions are definitely of higher complexity than rational functions of powers of variables. Additionally, if I understand correctly, the idea behind `FunctionExpand` is to simplify special functions into less special ones. And again, arguably trigonometric functions are more special than rational ones with certain powers.

Comment: no argument with the math. I was just musing that if we were to get that simplification by some command and blindly put it inside some loop we would be shooting ourselves in the foot as far as speed is concerned. But good question +1

Comment: @Kagaratsch Try using [`TrigToExp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp). As @bobbym explains, I think it's clear why FunctionExpand doesn't use it.

Comment: @Carl Woll That is pretty darn close to what the question asks for +1

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, `TrigToExp` works well here. Thank you!

Comment: @bobbym `FunctionExpand` is not necessarily about simplification, it is about expansion.