# Simplifying special functions in Mathematica?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

This question is a continuation of [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141292/functionexpand-does-not-yield-known-simplification) of mine, in an attempt to gain more understanding on how to use Mathematica to simplify special functions.

Consider the expression:

```
expr = Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 - z, 1 + z, -1];
```

If I try

```
FunctionExpand[expr]
```

> `Hypergeometric2F1[1, 3 - z, 1 + z, -1]`

Mathematica seems to suggest that no simpler expression for this hypergeometric function can be written down. However if we dig deeper, we can find an [identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/03/01/0006/) on the wolfram functions webpage that reduces `expr` to a simple expression involving just two gamma functions in this case:

```
Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, a - b + 3, -1] == ((Sqrt[Pi] Gamma[3 + a - b])/(2^a ((b - 1) (b - 2)))) (1/(Gamma[(a + 1)/2] Gamma[a/2 + 1 - b]) - a/(Gamma[a/2 + 1] Gamma[(a + 3)/2 - b]) + ((a (a + 1))/4) (1/(Gamma[(a + 3)/2] Gamma[a/2 + 2 - b])))/.a->1/.b->3-z//FullSimplify
```

> [image]

Considering that the identity can be found on the wolfram functions webpage, I presume that Mathematica should be aware of it. Therefore my question: Is it possible to obtain this simplification directly in Mathematica, without having to look it up manually on a webpage? If yes, what is the appropriate command?

Comment: "Considering that the identity can be found on the Wolfram Functions webpage, I presume that *Mathematica* should be aware of it." - not necessarily. Note that adding `FullSimplify[]` in your last snippet did not yield `True`.